# Pass safe-args when navigate to fragment

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

It's quite easy to pass `safe-args` when using [navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) through an action (with *directions class*).
But how to pass `safe-args` in case of using navigation to fragment directly?

```
navController?.navigate(R.id.detailFragment)
```

**nav_graph:**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
    android:name="com.example.ui.main.detail.DetailFragment"
    android:label=" "
    tools:layout="@layout/detail_fragment" >
    <argument
        android:name="templateCode"
        app:argType="string" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_start_guide"
        app:destination="@id/fillInfoFragment" />
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a good idea to use type-safe way because it take you **compile time safety** and some convenience.

This library will build argument's class `MyDestinationArgs`. You can use it to build `Bundle` and pass result to destination this way:

```
val args = DetailFragmentArgs.Builder("template_code").build().toBundle()
navController?.navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, args)
```

On receiver side, you can retrieve data also using arguments class:

```
val templateCode = SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments).templateCode
```

#### If we can't use *safeargs* library by some reasons,

we can pass data also inside `Bundle`. Suppose you have added

```
const val ARG_TEMPLATE_CODE = "templateCode"
```

constant in `companion object` of `DetailFragment` (`static final` field in Java)

Now you can pass data this way:

```
val args = Bundle()
args.putString(DetailFragment.ARG_TEMPLATE_CODE, "some_code")
navController?.navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, args)
```

And receiver fragment can obtain data from arguments:

```
arguments?.getString(ARG_TEMPLATE_CODE)
```

Or, if target destination is `Activity`, you can get data from `intent extras` (`ARG_TEMPLATE_CODE` constant now from destination activity):

```
intent?.extras?.getString(ARG_TEMPLATE_CODE)
```

Read more in documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Arguments) and [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Safe-args).

Answer (score 1):

The safe way is to define global action in case of need to navigate to fragment "directly"

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
    android:name="com.example.ui.main.detail.DetailFragment"
    android:label=" "
    tools:layout="@layout/detail_fragment" >
    <argument
        android:name="templateCode"
        app:argType="string" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_start_guide"
        app:destination="@id/fillInfoFragment" />
</fragment>

<action
    android:id="@+id/action_detail_fragment"
    app:destination="@id/fillInfoFragment" />
```

then

```
findNavController().navigate(NavGraphDirection.actionDetailFragment(templateCode))
```

Comment: For some reason i am unable to find NavGraphDirection.
When using specific actions for fragment to fragment it's ok, but for global action I don't get action generated. Do you know why?

Comment: @obey try to rebuild app